# Equal intervals on log scale

Tags: r, logarithm, function

I want to make a plot in which the horizontal axis is log scaled, ranging from 1 to 1000. I want to divide the horizontal axis into $n$ equal intervals, where "equal" means that it appears equal in the log axis. For example, if dividing into 2 intervals, they will be [1,?] and [?, 1000] where ? is some value between 10 and 50 according to the appearance of the plot.

In R, if it is not log scale, we can use `seq()` function.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to get the value(s) of "?" or how to specify such values as tick marks position in R's `plot()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ggplot2` package that is using the `scales` package himself.

the `scales` function `scale_x_log10()` define your X axis as log. The break parameter allows you to input a function such as `break_width()` or `pretty_breaks()`. However you can also pass a vector as an input.
Therefore all we have to do is to calculate the value of our splits ourselves and send the vector as an argument. Et voila

```
Even_log_scale_generator<-function(length_axis=1000,splits=10){
  z <- ln(length_axis) # initial axis length scaled to log
  a<-seq(0,z,z/splits) # dividing the scaled axis in splits
  a<-exp(a) #going back to unscaled values
  return(a)
}


y=rnorm(999, 0.02, 0.2)
M = data.frame(X = 1:1000, Y=10)
for (i in 2:1000)
  M[i, "Y"] = M[i-1, "Y"] * (1 + y[i-1])
ggplot(M, aes(x = X, y = Y)) + geom_line() + scale_x_log10(breaks=Even_log_scale_generator(1000,5))
```

For prettier results you might want to `round()` the returned vector